# lxml, flat_namespace and starting the program with or without python

Tags: python, command-line-interface, lxml

Hmmm I had an interesting issue and I don't understand why, but would love to.

```
→ python -V
Python 2.7.1
```

Let's check how my my program is starting

```
→ head -2 myprog.py
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# encoding: utf-8
```

Let's check what it returns

```
→ /usr/bin/env python2.7
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

OK so far so good. Let's try to execute the code.

```
→ python myprog.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foobar/myprog.py", line 16, in <module>
    from lxml.html import html5parser
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _htmlParseChunk
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
```

hmmm ok. lxml… there are plenty of other stackoverflow talking about this specific issue. **BUT** Weird because I have another script working perfectly with the same module. So I decided to look at the way I was using the other scripts, and I have seen that I was starting it directly.

```
→ ~/myprog.py -h
usage: myprog.py [-h] -u USERNAME [-o ARCHIVEPATH] [-f FILE_FORMAT]

Export html content from Zorglub
```

So when I'm using python for starting it, it doesn't work. When I use the program directly it is working. **WHY?** A python expert in the room?

Comment: I was digging around in the Python source earlier and found a lot of #ifdef'ed magic for OSX that uses the paths by which the interpreter is invoked to set up stuff for dlopen, specifically, whether to put various `/Library/Frameworks` things in.  See if `/usr/bin/python myprog.py -h` and/or `/usr/bin/python ~/myprog.py -h` makes any difference here (I have no idea if it will).

Comment: It doesn't make any difference :) It fails.

Comment: OK, just for the heck of it. instead of `python myprog.py -h` try `python2.7 myprog.py -h`.  Maybe these are two different versions of 2.7.1 and one doesn't work right? :-)

Comment: Oh I think we are getting closer ;) see the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @torek you put me on the right lane.

```
→ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
```

Which gives

```
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root 62 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x 6 root  1 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/python-config*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root  1 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/python2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root  1 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/python2.5-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5-config*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root  1 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root  1 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root  1 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root  1 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root 62 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/pythonw*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root  1 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/pythonw2.5 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/pythonw2.5*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root  1 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root  1 2011-08-15 21:09 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7*
```

ok let's try

```
→ /usr/bin/python
```

And we get

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _htmlParseChunk
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
>>>
```

Then the other one

```
→ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

And we get

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lmxl import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lmxl
>>>
```

Oh and to make things slightly worse… :) python3 is in /usr/local/bin/

```
→ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root 2 2006-11-09 05:05 /usr/local/bin/python2.5-config*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/python3-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3-32*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3-config*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/python3.3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/python3.3-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3-32*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/python3.3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3-config*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/python3.3m -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3m*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/python3.3m-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3m-config*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2012-03-02 13:43 /usr/local/bin/pythonbrew_install*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/pythonw3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pythonw3*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/pythonw3-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pythonw3-32*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/pythonw3.3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pythonw3.3*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 1 2013-02-25 12:50 /usr/local/bin/pythonw3.3-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pythonw3.3-32*
```

Se we are not there yet, but I have least two copies of python 2.7